# Clipping raster with Rasterio and Fiona

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to clip a raster data using a watershed as a bound. I've tried it out by using Fiona and Rasterio.

**Here there is my code:**

```
import fiona
import rasterio
from rasterio.rio.clip import clip
with fiona.open("oreto_bacino2.shp", "r") as shapefile:
    geoms = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]

with rasterio.open("cn.asc") as src:
    out_image, out_transform = clip (geoms, src, crop=True)
    out_meta = src.meta.copy()

out_meta.update({
    "driver": "GTiff",
    "height": out_image.shape[1],
    "width": out_image.shape[2],
    "transform": out_transform
})

with rasterio.open("cn_masked.tif", "w", **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(out_image)
```

**This is the mistake I've obtained:**

```
complete_var = '_%s_COMPLETE' % (prog_name.replace('-', '_')).upper()
```

Which throws this error:

> AttributeError: 'rasterio._io.RasterReader' object has no attribute 'replace'

Does anybody know the correct way to do my operation?

Answer (score 1):

The `rio` functions like `rasterio.rio.clip.clip` cannot be called as Python functions, since they already have a command-line interface attached to them (all those decorators) and are optimized for getting their parameters from there.

You can instead [look into the code of the clip function](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/5d2b791dac39efec5873620ccac24f385c149778/rasterio/rio/clip.py#L108-L136) to see how it achieves the clipping and mimick that. It basically creates a window from the bounds of your geometry and reads from the source raster with that window (windowed read).

Or you can follow the [example from the docs](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/masking-by-shapefile.html) that uses `rasterio.mask.mask(..., crop=True)` and not only clips to the bounds but also masks pixels outside your geometry, which might be even closer to what you want to do.